# How do I draw this pendulum with the pendulum displaced to the right instead of the left?

Tags: diagrams, physics

[image]

Hi, can somebody help me draw this diagram but with the pendulum displaced to the right? I'm new to LaTeX so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: I tried to learn how to draw images on LaTeX but i don't know how to draw something like this.

Comment: You can use https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TSE.

Here is a solution with tikz. You can easily change the first parameters. Comments are added in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nHoles{9} % defines the number of holes
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dHoles{-1.5} % defines the distance between holes
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pivot{2} % number of the pivot (starting from 1)
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{30} % angle of the rotation
    \pgfmathsetmacro\barOffset{10} % offset between holes and bar edges
    \def\lPos{right} % position of the labels L and l
    \pgfmathsetmacro\signL{sign(sin(\angle))} % to determine on which side putting the arrows
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={\angle:(0,\pivot*\dHoles cm)}] % a scope to rotate the bar
      \foreach \H in {1,...,\nHoles} % a loop to draw the holes
      {\draw (0, \H*\dHoles cm) circle [radius=4pt] node (H_\H) {};}
      \draw [very thick, red] (0, \pivot*\dHoles cm) circle [radius=4pt] node (P) {}; % redraw the pivot and name it P
      \draw ($(H_1.center)+(\barOffset pt, \barOffset pt)$) rectangle ($(H_\nHoles.center)-(\barOffset pt, \barOffset pt)$); % draw the bar
      \draw [thin, dotted] ($(H_1)+(0, \barOffset pt)$) --++ (\signL*2 cm, 0);
      \draw [thin, dotted] ($(H_\nHoles)-(0, \barOffset pt)$) --++ (\signL*2cm, 0);
      \draw [<->] ($(H_1)+(\signL*2 cm, \barOffset pt)$) -- ($(H_\nHoles)+(\signL*2 cm, -\barOffset pt)$) node [ \lPos=3pt, pos=.5]  {$L$}; % label L
      \fill ($(H_1)!.5!(H_\nHoles)$) circle [radius=2pt] coordinate (CM); % define the center
      \draw [thin, dotted] (P.center) --++ (\signL*1cm, 0);
      \draw [thin, dotted] (CM.center) --++ (\signL*1cm, 0);
      \draw [<->] ($(P.center)+(\signL*1 cm, 0)$) -- ($(CM)+(\signL*1 cm, 0)$) node [ \lPos=3pt, pos=.5]  {$\ell$}; % label l
    \end{scope} % end of the rotated part
    \node at ($(CM)+(\signL*2*\barOffset pt, 0)$) {$CM$}; % add the CM label
    \draw [dashed] (0,\dHoles) -- (0, \nHoles*\dHoles); % vertical line
    \draw [->] ($(P)+(0, 1.5*\dHoles)$) arc [start angle=90,end angle=90+\angle, radius=1.5*\dHoles cm] node [anchor=north, pos=.5] {$\theta$}; % angle
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the picture below.

[image]

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know how I can make the image smaller in the text?

Comment: Sure. Just replace `\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']` by `\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=.4, every node/.style={scale=.5}]`.

Comment: You are honestly a lifesaver. Thank you so much!

Comment: @NealBatra, in the future, remember that on this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed (as you can see) because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.